# atersik waitexten no choice default

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I am trying to make an IVR menu with asterisk. My question is if the caller does not choose during WaitExten how can I tell asterisk to go to [egy_mainmenu_1] ?

My code is:

```
exten => s,n,Background(bizt_welcome3)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(5)
exten => _[12345],1,Goto(egy_mainmenu_${EXTEN},s,1)
exten => s,n,Goto(egy_mainmenu_1,s,1)

[egy_mainmenu_1]
exten => s,1,NoOp(${QUEUESTATUS})
exten => s,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=KGFB)
exten => s,n,Queue(q-egy,hRt,,,3600)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "TIMEOUT"]?timeout)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "FULL"]?full)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "JOINEMPTY"]?joinempty)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${QUEUESTATUS}" = "LEAVEEMPTY"]?leaveempty)
exten => s,n,Goto(hup)
```

Answer (score 0):

If caller do nothing will be timeout.

In your case it will go next extension after WaitExect, i.e goto.

but please note, **n** is  always prevous line priority+1.
In your case **n** near goto is 2, so it will not work.

You should put all dialplan for **s** first, after that other choices.

```
exten => s,1,Background(bizt_welcome3); no way put n if no prevous priority, use 1
exten => s,n,WaitExten(5)            ; now n is 2
exten => s,n,Goto(egy_mainmenu_1,s,1); now n is 3

exten => _[12345],1,Goto(egy_mainmenu_${EXTEN},s,1); this is other ext
exten => _[12345],n,Noop; here is n=2 AGAIN.
```

You can see result by dooing via asterisk console

```
asterisk -r
dialplan show
```